# Can't apt update on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt

Here is log.

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG D530E028F59EAE4D Launchpad PPA for NoobsLab
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
W: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: 11.04 is beyond end of life. I highly advise you upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu. Although you can find advice on how to use old repos, there are serious security vulnerabilities in 11.04

Comment: Sorry. I wrong. My ubuntu is 14.04

Comment: sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.backup  .Then run sudo apt-get update

Comment: Use an alternate mirror

Comment: @sohel4r 
i get this :(

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps-dependencies/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Maybe you use old repo. try @bodhi.zazen

Comment: try rebooting your system and then try again